# Google Play Saved Games can't open Snapshot with SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

i can load the snapshot properly:

```
{"m_metadataList":[{"m_coverImageUri":"content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/f3a3c6d5/26","m_description":"6,1,1,123","m_hashCode":836811868,"m_playedTime":0,"m_progressValue":-1,"m_title":"CardCrawlSaveGame"}]}
```

but when i try to open the snapshot i get a SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND error:

```
{"m_error":{"m_code":2,"m_message":"com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 26570: SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND"}}
```

The snapshot was saved with an old implementation of the Saved Games API (via [Android Native](https://unionassets.com/android-native-plugin/saved-games-142)) and can be successfully opened with the old version of my game (snapshot data is there and also is viewable in the hidden app data on my Google Drive).

[Google Drive App Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFVHx.jpg)

I recently updated my Unity plugins (Android Native to [Android Native Pro](https://unionassets.com/android-native-pro/saved-games-682)) and the error only occurs with the latest Saved Games API implementation. The strange thing is that this only happens for 1 of my 3 games in which i use the exact same plugin/code implementation combination.

I'm kind of puzzled since the [Android docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClientStatusCodes.html#SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND) say that the snapshot does not exist on the server, but i can see snapshot data in google drive and my old version can load it just fine.

Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Can you provide logs of when saving (when it seems like it is not saving the data)? If they are long, you can use a Gist(https://gist.github.com/). Does the cross-device save/load eventually sync up? There can be some delay since the data needs to travel over the internet, be persisted, and then go back.

Comment: The problem is not the saving but the loading part. The snapshot is there but it's content can't be opened. Here's a log: https://pastebin.com/EW0vD2eA